# javascript change div based on dropdown

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list with 2 options:

```
<select name="list" size="1">
   <option value=1>Option 1</option>
   <option value=2>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

And i want to set `<span id=tag></span>` to display different text depending on which option is highlighted in the dropdown. How can I do this?

Comment: `<span=tag>` isn't valid HTML. Try `<span id="tag">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question is pretty vague but in general you would do something like this:

Html:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="list" size="1">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<span id="tag"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
//cache the select and span elements
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
    tag = document.getElementById("tag");

//when it changes
mySelect.onchange = function() {
       //change the tag innerHTML checking the selected value of the select
       tag.innerHTML = mySelect.value === "1" ? "some text" : "some other text";
}
```

You could change the ternary operator (`? :`) for a few if statements, if you need more conditions.

Notice that I've added an Id to the `<select>`. You can avoid the caching part if you want to get the span each time the select changes for some reason

Comment: if the option values are text `<option value=one>` it doesnt seem to work. Or am i doing something silly?

Comment: Try using quotes `<option value="one">text</option>` and then remember to change the value in the `onchange` method. It should work, it's not restricted to numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an onchange event handler on your `<select>`:

```
<select name="list" id="list">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>

<span id="tag"></span>

<script>
  // Get references to the objects you need (<select> and <span>)
  var list = document.getElementById('list');
  var tag = document.getElementById('tag');

  // When the list value changes, set the innerHTML of the <span>
  list.onchange = function() {
    tag.innerHTML = this.value;
  };
</script>
```

Notice in the above that I've added id attributes to both your select and span elements.  This allows me to easily get a reference to them in Javascript.

It's also important for my example that the script is executed after the elements are rendered, otherwise the `document.getElementById` call won't return a reference to them. You could get around this limitation by moving the script into a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) handler.

Here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wtv3H/) of it working.

Comment: If you wanted to copy some part of my answer, at least you could be a little more creative with the words :P (I'm not mad or anything)

Comment: @Nicosunshine weird - I didn't see your answer, even after I'd posted mine.  Kind of strange how close we came in writing it out eh?

Comment: Great minds think alike, or coincidence...probably coincidence.